# Is it possible create and query a local Postgres database on an Android device?

Tags: android, postgresql, gis

I want to store some app data in a local Postgres database. I don't need it to be accessible through internet or anything. I could use sqlite but I need Postgres's GIS features for my application.

Is it possible for an app to do this? (without rooting the phone)

or Can you compile the Postgres source code to work on Android?

Comment: @mr.incognito this link does not answer my question, as you can see the workaround provided is for sqlite, and it has no information on weather you can compile postgres on android...

Comment: There is no PostgreSQL port for Android. So no.

Comment: PostgreSQL cannot be compiled for Android. And it really would make very little sense: PostgreSQL is particularly suited to large databases and multi-user access. Also, it is unlikely that you need PostGIS's functionality on an Android device. There are multiple database / spatial data apps out there; or develop your own from available toolkits.

Comment: @Patrick a little more research shows me that it can be done with a lot of hackery, effectively porting it myself... But I am not sure I am capable of doing that right now...

Comment: What GIS features does your app need?

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/)? It's an extension to SQLite very similar to PostGIS. AFAIK it's available for Android and may have the features you require.