# How to use PostgreSQL offline local storage on a React-Native app?

Tags: postgresql, react-native, local-storage

I'm creating my first app and I'd want to keep using the stack I've learned. Therefore I've created a React-Native app that has an Express server and a PostgreSQL database. I can connect to a server that already exists (for instance, using my localhost server on Windows) but I can't figure out how to create a database server per device or some kind of PostgreSQL local storage. Is there no solution? Is there no way to use a local port on an Android/IOs device as it's used on Windows?

I left a list of posts that I've read but couldn't find an answer.

- Most exhaustive answer and plenty of solutions but no one using something like Postgres/SQL or related

  - [What are my options for storing data when using React Native? (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android)
- No answer (just an alternative) and it's an old question:

  - [Is it possible create and query a local Postgres database on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518543/is-it-possible-create-and-query-a-local-postgres-database-on-an-android-device)
- Same as before (answer is to use Realm):

  - [App local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523508/app-local-database)
- More suitable but is there no answer and it's written in Java.

  - [Can't connect Android application to local PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501548/cant-connect-android-application-to-local-postgresql-database)
- Remote access (not local storage) but following the d-vine answer it seems possible:

  - [React Native - connect to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995930/react-native-connect-to-postgresql-database/34996800#34996800)
- Postgres's docs on creating a database server:

  - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/server-start.html

Edit: added all this related post on local storage

- A lot of question about local storage and almost all answers saying to use AsyncStorage:

  - [How to store data in local storage with react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154940/how-to-store-data-in-local-storage-with-react-native)
  - [How do i use localstorage in React native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597155/how-do-i-use-localstorage-in-react-native)
  - [Local Storage - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115591/local-storage-react-native)
  - [React Native Local Storage Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989395/react-native-local-storage-best-practice)

Comment: Do you need it to be Postgres?  AsyncStorage uses SQLite on Android, for example, but mostly only exposes key-value access. What are your database needs?

Comment: I'd argue that the pains you'd have to go through to get a PostgreSQL instance running locally.. are on the order of magnitude larger, than switching to SQLite which is extremely well supported.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I did a skim reading through different options before and I'm currently using SQLite. It's almost the same as PostgreSQL and at this very moment, I had no problems. But if you had already written the code it'd be useful to use it. I thought it wouldn't be so complex to have a server.

Comment: Re *"d-vine"*: Do you mean *"[divine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divine#Adjective)"*?

Comment: The user name is d-vine: https://stackoverflow.com/users/255765/d-vine